# Add PNG as a layer in Mapnik

Tags: gdal, mapnik, png

I'm playing around with Mapnik and trying to add a PNG image over a map created from an XML file. This is my XML file:

```xml
<Map background-color="white" minimum-version="0.7.2" srs="+init=epsg:3395">
    <Style name="population">
        <Rule><PolygonSymbolizer fill="#c7e9b4" /></Rule>
    </Style>

    <Layer name="countries" srs="+init=epsg:3395">
        <StyleName>population</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
            <Parameter name="type">shape</Parameter>
            <Parameter name="file">world_merc</Parameter>
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>
</Map>
```

And my code is like this:

```py
import mapnik

m = mapnik.Map(600,400)
xml = 'population.xml'
mapnik.load_map(m, xml)

s = mapnik.Style()
rule = mapnik.Rule()
sym = mapnik.RasterSymbolizer()
rule.symbols.append(sym)
s.rules.append(rule)
m.append_style('Raster Style', s)

lyr = mapnik.Layer('GDAL Layer')
#lyr.srs = '+init=epsg:3395'
lyr.datasource = mapnik.Gdal(file='data.png', bbox=(0,0,1000,1000))
lyr.styles.append('Raster Style')
m.layers.append(lyr)

m.zoom_all()
mapnik.render_to_file(m,'map.png')
```

When that `lyr.srs` line is uncommented, the image is not shown, only the XML layer is there. When it is commented out, only a small part of the image is shown above the XML layer, the lower left corner of the image seems to be at the position of the origin of the SRS.

I just think that PNG files don't have info about where they should be, so the parameter bbox of the [Gdal](https://mapnik.org/docs/v2.2.0/api/python/mapnik-module.html#Gdal) function seems to be good; however, it appears that that parameter doesn't have any effect in my code. The documentation is for mapnik 2.2 and my mapnik version is 3.0 so I'm not sure though.

Could someone tell me whether the parameter bbox has the same meaning as I think, and how I can control the position and size of the image displayed on the map?

Comment: Do you have an accompanying file with extension `pgw`, `pngw` or `wld` with the same content you will use for a accompanying `tfw` file to a Geotiff (only the extension change)? Related to the fact, that georeferencing for PNG is in an outside file according to doc https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/png.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [gdal.Translate](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Translate) to convert your PNG to a georeferenced GeoTIFF:

```
from osgeo import gdal
bounds = [west, north, east, south]
gdal.Translate('output.tif', 'input.png', outputSRS='EPSG:4326', outputBounds=bounds)
```

Use the coordinates from your bounding box as the `outputBounds`, making sure the SRS is correct (probably 4326). You can then include this GeoTIFF as a [raster layer](http://mapnik.org/mapnik-reference/#3.0.22/raster). The XML would look like this:

```
<Layer name="geotiff" srs="+init=epsg:4326">
    <StyleName>geotiff</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
        <Parameter name="type">gdal</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="file">output.tif</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="format">tiff</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
</Layer>

<Style name="geotiff">
    <Rule>
        <RasterSymbolizer scaling="lanczos" />
    </Rule>
</Style>
```

That `bbox` option you were using: I'm not sure what it does, but I assume it just sets the layer *extent*, as opposed to actually georeferencing the raster.

Comment: I think your answer can resolve the problem of showing the data from the image onto the map, but I still want to know how we should add an image. That type of data source is allowed, so there must be some way to use it.